# Unable to read mails of nsf file programatically

Tags: c#, .net, lotus-notes

Am trying to programatically read mails of nsf file using c#.
But iam not able to get the views.
following are the code that i have used to get views

```
_InboxView = _serverDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)");
```

My nsf file template is totally different.

Why am not able to get the views? please suggest.

Comment: Do you get an error when that line of code runs? What is it?  And please explain what you mean by "My nsf file is totally different". You are asking about reading emails, so what exactly is different in it from the standard mail template?

Comment: Another imortant question: are you running your application on Win64 or Win32. If you are running it on Win64, are you building it as a 64 bit application or 32? This is important because the Notes COM classes that are used for the C# interop are not supported on 64 bits. They mostly work, and GetView is not one of the calls that has known problems, but it might affect other parts of your application.

Comment: In Lotus Script I would check first, if _serverDatabase has a value: `if not _serverDatabase Is Nothing` Maybe it is `if (!_serverDatabase == null)` or something like that in C#

Comment: Did you check the server log (log.nsf) for an error message

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you posted takes the database (did you check, if _serverDatabase is initialized, by the way?) and tries to open a folder or view with the programmatic name "($Inbox)". In your template that name could really be everything.

You either need to ask the developer of the app for the name of that folder / view (they are not different for access via the NotesView- Class), or you need to find it out by yourself.

To find it out, you could use the Notes client menu: Try `View - Go To...` and identify the name of the View that is shown in your screenshot. If your view looks "hierarchical" (you need to click a plus to find it), then compose the viewname from the complete tree using backslashes, e.g. "All Views\Your Special view".

It may be easier to find out the name of the view, if you have Domino Designer installed and have enough rights to open the database in designer: There you can simply find the view in the views section or a folder in the folders section and copy the name or the alias of it (both are equally valid).

Comment: Views named "(...)" are hidden, so you will not find them with View - Go To... There is a special key you have to press, so you can see hidden views, too (but I don't know in the moment)."$(Inbox)" is a standard view and will not "be everything", but the Inbox view.